# rviz display is blacked out

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS indigo. My PC configuration is Dell Vostro intel i5 processor.  I have installed all the essential dependencies of rviz.

Could you tell me what's the problem?

[image: the image is here]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279211/rviz-display-is-blacked-out/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
Could you please attach your image directly to the question? I've given you enough karma to do that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
Btw: you have 3 answered questions, but none are accepted. If those answers are in fact correct, you should accept them. I wouldn't have to give you additional karma in that case.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2018-01-09**:
QT might be picking up the wrong color from the Ubuntu theme. Try changing to the default theme in Ubuntu.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2018-01-09**:
Another possibility is that you have a QT environment variable set that is overriding the theme. You might run `printenv | grep QT` to see what you have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well actually I could not understand what to do so I removed ubuntu and installed again and ROS as well. And now it works fine. I don't know what was the problem. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) with karma: 88 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0